# MySQL query parse error

Tags: php, mysql

```
$week_leave = mysql_query("select count(id),leave.id from `leave`, `users` where leave.backgroundColor = 'Green' and leave.id=(select U_id from `users` where users.username='$_SESSION['username']')");
```

Gives the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)
```

I know the problem lies in the sub query. Any suggestions ?

Comment: typo error: `leave`, `users`

Comment: In your query i see both ` and ' characters ... but it might be a posting problem, could you check?

Comment: oh boy still using mysql_query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this you have to set the data vetween curly braces  `{$_SESSION['username']}`

```
$week_leave = mysql_query("select count(id),leave.id from `leave`, `users` where leave.backgroundColor = 'Green' and leave.id=(select U_id from `users` where users.username='{$_SESSION['username']}')");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this below answer as problem lies at $_SESSION variable

```
$week_leave = mysql_query("select count(id),leave.id from `leave`, `users` where leave.backgroundColor = 'Green' and leave.id=(select U_id from `users` where users.username='".$_SESSION['username']."')");
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

```
$_SESSION['username']
```

the two single quotes conflict with the other two outside. You can do as @Osama Jetawe suggets or you can just assign this value to a variable like this:

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
```

and then use `'$username'` in your query

Comment: The single quotes don't conflict, this is a misunderstanding of how such strings are parsed. Using numeric indexes without quotes wouldn't work either. It's just that the array index operator is not taken into account without curly braces.

Comment: Glad to learn a new thing! Thanks @Archimedix

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  $week_leave = mysql_query("select count(id),leave.id from `leave`, `users` where leave.backgroundColor = 'Green' and leave.id=(select U_id from `users` where users.username='".$_SESSION['username']."')");
```